# How to turn these N queries to one

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a performance problem with a table I'm working on and it seems I'm unable to find a good solution to this issue. I create the due indexes but we have millions rows and query is still very slow.

The table represents a text splitted in token with other information for each token. I know that some of you may think this could have been done using a Full-text search engine but we can't. Please, trust me.

The table schema is the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `midia_lemmatized_text`
(
    `IdFile` CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    `Position` INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `WordForm` VARCHAR(48) NOT NULL,
    `Pos` VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
    `Lemma` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`IdFile`,`Position`),
    INDEX `midia_lemmatized_text_FI_2` (`Pos`),
    INDEX `midia_lemmatized_text_FI_3` (`WordForm`),
    CONSTRAINT `midia_lemmatized_text_FK_1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`IdFile`)
        REFERENCES `midia_metadata` (`Id`),
    CONSTRAINT `midia_lemmatized_text_FK_2`
        FOREIGN KEY (`Pos`)
        REFERENCES `midia_pos` (`Pos`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARACTER SET='utf8';
```

where

- `IdFile` is an external key
- `Position` is a index position that specify the position of the current token inside the file
- `WordForm` is the token itself
- `PoS` is the Part-of-Speech of the word form
- `Lemma` is the lemma of the word form

Example of row:

```
1, 1, 'The', 'ART', 'The'
1, 2, 'table', 'NOUN', 'table'
1, 3, 'is', 'VER', 'be'
...
```

### The query

The problematic query is like the following:

> Find all the word forms that are "rivolgimento" in context, that is
>   surrounded by the previous and following **10** words

**Note**: 10 can be another number and a context word is also a comma, dot and so on.

An example of the result is:

> cuor trasparente , mi par bene di conchiuder con affettuoso
>   **rivolgimento** alla dissimulazione stessa . O virtù , che sei il

What I do now is retrieve all the `IdFile` and `Position` numbers for each matched row and then loop over them to retrieve the previous and following N words. As you can understand, this implies 1 + N queries and for a large N it leads to a very slow response.

The main problem is also that people can also search using REGEX on the column and this slow even more the query.

I thought to use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) but don't know exactly how.

Comment: Consider posting up an sqlfiddle TOGETHER WITH the desired result. (I put it in CAPITALS so that you don't forget. But you will. Everyone does :-( )

Comment: Your query needs to be more specific.  What do you mean by the previous and following "N" words?  In a particular order?  How far back and forward do you look?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Updated. Is it now more clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the hints provided by Gordon Linoff, I came out with this query:

```
select ltr.*, group_concat(lt.WordForm separator ' ')
from midia_lemmatized_text ltr join
     midia_lemmatized_text lt
     on ltr.`WordForm` = 'rivolgimento' and
        lt.position between ltr.position - 10 and ltr.position + 10 and
        lt.IdFile = ltr.IdFile
group by ltr.IdFile, ltr.position;
```

Answer (score 1):

The way that you would get 10 words around "rivolgimento":

```
select lt.*
from lemmatized_text ltr join
     lemmatized_text lt
     on ltr.lemma = 'rivolgimento' and
        lt.position between ltr.position - 10 and ltr.position + 10;
```

If you want the words in one row, per appearance of 'rivolgimento', then something like:

```
select ltr.position, group_concat(lt.lemma separator ' ')
from lemmatized_text ltr join
     lemmatized_text lt
     on ltr.lemma = 'rivolgimento' and
        lt.position between ltr.position - 10 and ltr.position + 10
group by ltr.position;
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Unfortunately none of these works. The first error is the use of lemma instead of wordform (easy change). In addition the second query retrieve more than 20 + 1 words.